# how to send a request from web-server to android?

Tags: android, post, chat, message

I am working on a chatting app. In which one user sends message to another user. So there are two users(user1 and user2). when user1 sends a message to user2. On back-end I am sending the message to my web-server using post method, then user2 is always sending get request to server and receives the message in response. In this way my job is done but my question is that if there is any way to send a request from web-server to phone? and user2 can directly receive the message without sending request to the server all the time. Please help!

Comment: I dnt know any such method so that web server can send a request to phone. But you send push notification GCM to user2 when ever web-server gets a message and user2 gets notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Linesh said above, could be one possible solution but rather unconventional using GCM for chatting purpose; instead you can make use of standard web sockets, which could be easily implemented in node.js, or PHP,Python, whatever server side programming you are supposed to be using. also based on websockets , have look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/) or you can make use of some third party chatting API's like [quickblox](https://quickblox.com/), or [pub-nub](https://www.pubnub.com/) or even AWS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way. You can use GCM to send the msg to phone.

The working would be like.

1. register both the devices with gcm and store the registration id to  your server with the unique user id
2. when user1 sends some msg to server. then get the registration id of user2 and send the msg to gcm server.
3. user 2 will get the msg when he connects himself to some network.

this links will might help you

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

One big downside to using 100% GCM is that it can tie you to Android unless you take extra steps in your design to ensure that you can use other services too - with an improper implementation you could only do chat between Android phones but not, for example, Android to iOS, Windows Phone to Android, or Android to desktop client. This ends up being a significant downside since, based on statistics I saw recently, Android has an approximately 66% market share. While this sounds like a lot, this limitation would mean that you couldn't chat with 1/3 of people. iOS, Windows, and Amazon phones/tablets all use different push notification services. (One possible solution to this is to use AWS SNS Push, which will act as a "matchmaker" for different push notification services; this would improve the platform independence to some degree).

SignalR is another option. There are actually quite a few examples of chat apps out there that use it - it seems to be the canonical example actually.